# Remove WWW from Nginx with Certbot

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am a confused why I cannot get **www** to remove off this domain name. At the **bottom** of this Nginx configuration is the **Remove WWW** Part. I am uncertain if **Certbot** is having any issues with this or not, does anyone see the mistake?

The site is live, both `www` and `non www` work. I am trying to get **only** www.  I haven't asked this question for years, I may be rusty -- give tin man some oil!

```
upstream jessered {
    server 127.0.0.1:3000;
}

server {

    server_name jesse.red www.jesse.red;
    root /var/www/jesse.red/;

    # ---------------------------------------------------------------
    # Location
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------
    location / {
        proxy_pass          http://jessered;
        #proxy_http_version  1.1;                                                       
        proxy_set_header    Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header    Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header    Host $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_cache_bypass  $http_upgrade;
        proxy_read_timeout  90;
    }

    # ---------------------------------------------------------------
    # SSL
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------
    listen 443 ssl http2; # managed by Certbot
    gzip off;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.jesse.red/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot  
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.jesse.red/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    error_log /var/www/errors/jesse.red.error.log;
}

# ---------------------------------------------------------------
# Force SSL
# ---------------------------------------------------------------
server {
    if ($host = www.jesse.red) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = jesse.red) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
}


# ---------------------------------------------------------------
# Remove Non-www
# ---------------------------------------------------------------
server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  server_name www.jesse.red;
  return 301 $scheme://jesse.red$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: Your first `server` block should be `server_name jesse.red;`. You have `www.jesse.red` listed on both secure servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to use `jesse.red` and not `www.jesse.red`, then don't include `www.jesse.red` in the `server_name` definition.

Your if block is not necessary and incorrect, because if `$host = www.jesse.red`, the `return 301 https://$host$request_uri` will still be `return 301 https://www.jesse.red/$request_uri`.

Your overall configuration can be tidy up a little bit as:

```
# Force SSL
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name jesse.red;
    root /var/www/jesse.red/;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

# SSL configuration
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2; # managed by Certbot
    gzip off;
    ssl on;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.jesse.red/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot  
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.jesse.red/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    error_log /var/www/errors/jesse.red.error.log;

    location / {
        proxy_pass          127.0.0.1:3000;
        #proxy_http_version  1.1;                                                       
        proxy_set_header    Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header    Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header    Host $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_cache_bypass  $http_upgrade;
        proxy_read_timeout  90;
    }
}
```